# Django problem accessing Admin while my main DB is Mongo

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm quite new using Django and Python and I'm working on a project that is yet started.

Default Database is MongoDB where I have users and I can authenticate in the login page of the app.

Now we installed a 'helpdesk' app that is a ticketing system and we would like to use Admin that is disabled in our project.
I added the Admin app in Settings and Url but I don't have any access to any user.

I tried to create a superuser with python manage.py createsuperuser but it gives me this error:

> TypeError at /admin/
>   int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ObjectId'

In django/contrib/auth we made some changes for example:

```
def _get_user_session_key(request):
# This value in the session is always serialized to a string, so we need
# to convert it back to Python whenever we access it.
if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
    return ObjectId(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
```

Where appears this ObjectId, it seems that Admin is trying to access the user from MongoDB and not from helpdesk DB that is SQLite.

Probably my problem is that I don't understand about mixing databases and accessing.
I created a router with functions like:

```
class RouterDB:
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    print(model._meta.app_label)
    if model._meta.app_label == 'helpdesk' or model._meta.app_label == 'sites' or model._meta.app_label == 'admin':
        return 'helpdesk'
    return 'default'

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label == 'helpdesk'or model._meta.app_label == 'sites' or model._meta.app_label == 'admin':
        return 'helpdesk'
    return 'default'
```

Any help?

Comment: is "admin" an app you are creating? django has a built-in admin system. Im not sure what you are referring to. Also, maybe this could help?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @Hafnernuss Yes sorry, I'm referring to the build-in admin system from Django.
I've read this multi database documentation and I wrote my own Database Router where I say if app_label = ' sites' or 'admin' go to 'helpdesk' database that is sqlite but anyway I cannot access with any user to the admin django page.

Comment: Any update ?
To clarify, my main application make use of MongoDB and I use a SQLite DB to use 'helpdesk' application but I cannot access with any user to the Admin app that comes with Django.

Comment: can you verify that the user exists in your DB? Otherwhise I'm afraid I can't help you as I have never used django with 2 seperate DB systems before.

Comment: That's the problem.
Even If I create manually a user in the database I want, admin always try to connect to the Mongo Database ( I use MongoEngine ).

Comment: Do you absolutly _HAVE_ to use two different database systems? This seems odd to me, especially when dealing within the same project.

Comment: Actually, I'm using in the same Django Project 2 Apps:
- Main App with Mongo DB
-'Helpdesk' app ( Ticketing System ) that doesn't use Mongo, it uses SQLite or MySQL.

So to work with this I need both Databases right ? ( Maybe I'm wrong )
Also 'Admin' default app from Django doesn't work well with MongoEngine.

Comment: You have ONE Project with TWO apps, right? Your two apps being 'Helpdesk' and a 'main' app. I dont get why you would need two different databases. Usually there is one database per project, which houses models from your different apps.